# Obter item de um array com jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, array

Tenho a seguinte estrutura:

```
[{tabela: 'tabela1', coluna: 'coluna1'}, {tabela: 'tabela2', coluna: 'coluna2'}]
```

Preciso inserir esses dados dentro de uma `div` no formato:

> [TABELA.COLUNA]

No caso ficaria:

> [tabela1.coluna1] [tabela2.coluna2]

Mas não estou achando uma solução para isso com `jQuery`. Como poderia fazer isso ?

Comment: *"Obter item de um array com jQuery"*, não é preciso nem de jQuery: `object...[...]`, isso é o mesmo que indexar um objeto com o `.`, mas computadamente. Há várias maneiras de percorrer um array, entre elas a melhor é memorizar o seu tamanho e incrementar uma índice temporária até um certo limite. Também é possível percorrer a array diretamente assim: `for (var i = 0, item; (item = array[i++]) !== undefined;)`, um loop que quebra até chegar um item `undefined`.

Comment: No seu caso você só precisaria percorrer os itens de sua `Array`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Olá amigo espero poder ajudar na duvida

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  var json = [
                 { tabela: 'tabela1', coluna: 'coluna1'},
                 {tabela: 'tabela2', coluna: 'coluna2'}
             ];

    $.each(json,function (index, value) { 
       $('#conteudo').append('index =' + index + ' - ' + value.tabela +' - ' + value.coluna + '</br>');
    });  

});
</script>
<div id="conteudo"></div>
```

Comment: Valeu amigo, resolveu ;)